# Security in NowJS

Tags: node.js, socket.io, nowjs-sockets

I found NowJS and at the first sight, it looked very cool. I played around with the tutorials and it worked well.

Now I'm asking myself: How safe is this? Isn't it possible to inject XSS? The security issue is the biggest obstacle to use it in my apps.

Should I use socket.io like I have been, or is NowJS a good way to make it easier in a secure way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at this blog post from now.js:

http://blog.nowjs.com/nowjs-and-security

You can sanitize input through a server side function on the client side. Because they don't transfer the function body, you're pretty safe from injection.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. So you'd declare a function on the server in node.js that would validate the input.  You would "call" that function, however, from the client.

Answer (score 1):

XSS is something you have to protect yourself aganist, you have to validate incoming data and escape it before you put it into the document. However, the bigger issue would be bugs in nowjs that allow code execution or DOS aganist the server.

Answer (score 1):

Using the validator module [validator](https://github.com/chriso/node-validator) you can sanitize whats being sent:

```
everyone.now.distributeMessage = function(message) {
    var str = sanitize(message).xss();
    everyone.now.receiveMessage(str);
}
```